# How to return a co-ordinate structure in C

Tags: c, function, coordinates, return-value, coordinate-systems

```
float generateCoor()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    coordinate cd; //structure variable
    cd.rx = genRand();
    printf("X-coordinate: %.2f\n",rx);

    cd.ry = genRand();
    printf("Y-coordinate: %.2f\n",ry);
}
```

Now since one function cannot return two variables simultaneously, than how can I return the co-ordinates back to the main function?

Comment: A common approach is to define a `struct`, and pass around a pointer to it.

Comment: Does C still not let you actually return a struct?  I figured they'd have fixed that by now.  Oh. wait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of following :-

```
coordinate generateCoor() { ... return cd;} 

int main(){
coordinate c = generateCoor();
}
```

OR

```
void generateCoor(coordinate *cd) { ... }  

//Give it a proper name something like constructCoor 

int main(){
coordinate c;

generateCoor(&c);
}
```

Comment: If i were going to require the caller to pass in a struct, i might call the function something less "i create stuff"y.  Maybe `constructCoor`?

Comment: @cHao _"What's in a name?"_ ~William Shakespeare :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create structure, and return pointer to that structure.